# Vim Bindings Based on Key Position

Tags: vim, neovim

Is it possible to make Vim recognize bindings by the actual key positions, not by inputted symbols? If I change my layout, I can't use any bindings.

Let's say I switch my layout to Russian and I want <kbd>Ш</kbd> act like an <kbd>I</kbd>.

[image: Old dirty keyboard.]

Comment: Should be able to use langmap for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem with `xkblayout-state`: I just switch my system language layout with it every time I open Vim or enter a normal mode by these autocompletes:

```
" `0` is `en_US` in my case.
au VimEnter * silent !xkblayout-state set 0
au InsertLeave * silent !xkblayout-state set 0
```

---

Also I've found [another solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4761/24915) on Vi Stack Exchange:

> To use langmap in greek you can follow the example given in `:h 'langmap'` adding this line to your `vimrc` (Copying this line from here may not be a good idea since I'm really not sure of the encoding, yanking the line directly from the help file is probably safer):
>
> ```
> langmap=ΑA,ΒB,ΨC,ΔD,ΕE,ΦF,ΓG,ΗH,ΙI,ΞJ,ΚK,ΛL,ΜM,ΝN,ΟO,ΠP,QQ,ΡR,ΣS,ΤT,ΘU,ΩV,WW,ΧX,ΥY,ΖZ,αa,βb,ψc,δd,εe,φf,γg,ηh,ιi,ξj,κk,λl,μm,νn,οo,πp,qq,ρr,σs,τt,θu,ωv,ςw,χx,υy,ζz
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The positional key codes are called *scan codes* and are used and processed in hardware and low-level system software. You can't do anything with them in a portable application.

In principle, it's possible to go the other way and to map Russian/Cyrillic letters to the corresponding normal mode commands, like `nnoremap ш i` etc. However, that does not make much sense.

The point is that Vim already has built-in support for international key mappings in insert/replace mode. Simply add `set keymap=russian-jcukenwin` to vimrc and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> in insert mode to switch between the layouts.

In normal mode you should always stick to US/Latin. No need for system language switch.

Comment: This is kinda hell; what if I will use Dvorak, for example? All bindings will be broken. Most software (like games) rely on keys positions, so they do not differ layouts, so why Vim can't do it?

Comment: Anyway, thank you for `set keymap=russian-jcukenwin`, it's somehow would help; but how can I remap layout switch in Vim from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>?

Comment: @undefined (1) In Vim it's possible to map anything to anything. (2) There exists no such thing as "Russian Dvorak", but you can invent your own keymap if you really want. (3) Remapping <C-6> works as usual: `inoremap <KEY> <C-^>`.

Comment: I didn't mean Russian Dvorak, but the English one.

Comment: @undefined `set keymap=dvorak`

Comment: you completely misunderstood my comment.